# Can't add reference to a dll on Visual web developer 2010 Express

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new on this, so Thanks in Advance. I'm trying to add a Dll on my new project on .NET but it doesn't appear on Solution explorer. I can't even import on the code file. It's there any limitation adding dll on express edition?
I'm so newbie on .NET technology.

Comment: which kind of dll it is?? and which language project you have selected??

Comment: It's a .NET dll and the lanaguage is VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry. It has been a decision by Microsoft to remove *Reference* from
>   the default view to reduce the 'clutter'. However, your 'Show All
>   Files' setting will persist when you save your project. So if you show
>   all files once and then save, then it will always be on.
>
> You can also see your References in the Project designer, which you
>   can always keep open in a tab.

To add a reference in Visual Basic

> In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the
>   project.
>
> In the Project Designer, click the References tab.
>
> Click the Add button to open the Add Reference dialog box.
>
> In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of
>   component you want to reference.
>
> Select the components you want to reference, then click OK.
>
> In the opened window you are able to see whether your dll is
>   referenced or not. *If it is showing error when you are adding dll
>   reference then please update.*

Reference:
[How to: Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)
[How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)